# QueryDSL BooleanExpression exclude data if the field is null

Tags: spring-boot, filter, null, querydsl, boolean-expression

I have a problem when try to use a filter in a query that have a null field.

```
 if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(query)){
            expression = expression.and(qAdopt.name.containsIgnoreCase(query)
                    .or(qAdopt.code.containsIgnoreCase(query))
                    .or(qAdopt.specie.name.containsIgnoreCase(query))
                    .or(qAdopt.specie.code.containsIgnoreCase(query))
                    .or(qAdopt.rarity.stringValue().containsIgnoreCase(query)
                    .or(qAdopt.owner.nickName.containsIgnoreCase(query)));
        }
```

the values (Adopts) that not have Owner (Entity) are exclude for the response, althought the Adopt have match with the other fields (Name, code, specie.name, specie.code).
I dont know why the query exclude these adopts, since the owner.nickName should been optional.
If I remove the `.or(qAdopt.owner.nickName.containsIgnoreCase(query)));` all works correctly, but I want to filter by owner nickName.

I tried to put the validation in other places, but didn't work.